# Wordpress frontend multiple file upload

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload, frontend

```
<input name="image_url" type="file" /> <input name="Submit" type="Value" value="Přidat" />
```

I have this in html form and this in php :

```
    if ( $_FILES['image_url']['name'] != "" ) {
 global $wpdb;
 //For Uploading photo from front End
 if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
 }
 $overrides = array( 'test_form' => false);
 $file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['image_url'], $overrides);
 $content = $file['url'];
}
```

It works for a single file upload, however I need multiple files upload.
I´ve been searching for quite a while but I wasn´t able to do it myself. 
So if anybody could help me with this i´d be very grateful. And I also need variable that stores path of the file similar to $content in my code. Thak you for your time.I don´t want to use plugin since im uploading path to my own database.

Comment: its not duplicate and that other question doesnt help me at all.

Comment: yes it is a duplicate; don't argue with it and try it. You obviously haven't put any effort into it.

Comment: its not I m trying to work this out for two days now and as I see you are totally useless to me and unwilling to help. so atleast let other users help when you dont want to.

Comment: Alright, I´m screwed by somebody who doesnt want to help people, i dont see why are you on this site when you dont want questions answered and only mark them duplicate when they are different.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are already using Wordpress, why not use a plugin to do the work for you?

Some examples:

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/arfaly-mass-multi-file-uploader/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-file-uploader/

These plugins are also protected for malicious files like a PHP shell, your code  is not safe.